# Opencart 2. x Multi-store maintenance mode page on subdomains

Tags: php, .htaccess, opencart, admin

I've got OpenCart 2.x,
got multi-store "on",
got subdomains,
and I set maintenance mode "on".

The problem is that when I'm logged in as admin, I can see my store at mydomain.com without maintenance page, but when I go to subdomains at subdomain.mydomain.com I get maintenance page even if I'm logged in.

I tried `subdomain.mydomain.com/admin -> login` but it redirects me on mydomain.com after login.

Comment: Spoof the $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] at the top of index.php to be mydomain.com during maintenance mode. Or as early as you can.
And then undo it later ;) Maybe you can find the part in Opencart that poses the problem that way

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like this, redirect for all stores. You own ip allowed for access. Add one set for each of the stores in the beginning of .htaccess. Then add # in front of rows when not in maintenance.

```
#ReWriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^xxx\.xxx\.xxx\.xxx$ 
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site1.se$ [OR] 
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.site1.se$ 
#RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.subdomain.site1.se/$1 [R=302,L]
```